TypeScript Syntax Highlighting
I am trying to install yats.vim for TypeScript syntax. I used the usual Plug 'HerringtonDarkholme/yats.vim' in my vimrc. However, once I run PlugInstall the syntax highlighting in all .ts files is still the default highlighting from Vim.
Is there anyway to make sure this gets overridden?

Could you tell us why you think why you still have the default syntax highlighting? Could you share an example of typescript file, the expected colorization/syntax and the obtained colorization/syntax (screenshot will help).

Could you tell us which version of Vim you are using (:version)?

Vim is running version 9.1. The reason I think it isn't working is the syntax highlighting without the package installed is no different to when the package is installed.

As an example, when yats.vim is installed the keyword as is not highlighted when associating types (casting).

The typescript syntax of recent version of Vim (e.g. Vim 9.1) is based Herrington Darkholme's yats.vim I expect very little differences between the Herrington Darkholme's syntax and the default Vim typescript syntax for recent version of Vim.
To determine the highlight group of a keyword or construction you could:

Move your cursor on the keyword or construction
Run: echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')

For both syntax (the Vim 9.1 default or the HerringtonDarkholme's version) the highlight group of the as keyword is: typescriptCastKeyword.
Remark: It could be that you don't get the color you want because of the colorscheme you use.
